# How to adjust the tracking settings for this macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I use the following macro to check documents for US spelling (referencing an installed custom dictionary) and run a ligatures check, replacing any applicable ligatures. It works well but a number of formatting changes show up on the right hand side of the document, including:

1. Formatted: Font 12 pt
2. Formatted: Font Not Italic
3. Field Code Changed

I'm OK with the above things being checked, but I don't want them to be shown in the tracking (only the ligature replacement tracking should be shown).

Could someone help me to adjust the following macro code so that only the replacement of the ligatures shows in the  tracking? Many thanks in advance!

```
Sub USEnglish()
Selection.WholeStory
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim StrFnd As String, StrRep As String
Dim ArrRep(), oSuggestions, Rng As Range
Application.CheckLanguage = False
Application.ResetIgnoreAll
Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = True
Options.CheckGrammarWithSpelling = True
Options.ContextualSpeller = True
Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = True
ArrRep = Array("ff", "fi", "fl", "ffi", "ffl")
With ActiveDocument
  
  .TrackRevisions = True
  .Range.LanguageID = wdEnglishUS
  .SpellingChecked = False
  .GrammarChecked = False
  .ShowGrammaticalErrors = True
  .ShowSpellingErrors = True
  For i = 0 To UBound(ArrRep)
    StrFnd = ChrW(&HFB00 + i)
    StrRep = ArrRep(i)
    For j = 1 To 3
      On Error Resume Next
      With .StoryRanges(j).Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = StrFnd
        .Replacement.Text = StrRep
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
      Next j
  Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try your code with the .replacement.clearformatting line commented out.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion - unfortunately this doesn't change anything (the formatting tracking is still present).

Comment: In general, it's not a good idea to use the Unicode ligature characters U+FB00, U+FB01, etc.. These were encoded in Unicode only for compatibility with legacy encoding standards. Consider, for example: if somebody searches in your document for "office" they won't find occurrences because you have changed the word. It's better to leave ligatures as a font formatting/presentation issue rather than an encoding/spelling issue.

Comment: I agree that ligatures are best avoided - hence the replacement step in the code above (post-macro the ligatures in the text are replaced with standard letters, and "office", "difference" etc with separate "f" characters are now searchable).

This is fine as is - the issue I'd like to sort is the extra formatting tracking, per the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn off formatting tracking and restore it when you've finished.

```
With ActiveDocument
  .TrackFormatting = False
```

Field Code Changed is likely to be a result of the find and replace.